# Showing only a particular div in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So i have 2 ng-repeats like so:

```
<div ng-repeat = "car in cars track by car" >
<div ng-repeat = "driver in drivers track by driver">

<div>
 <label>  {{driver}}    </label>
</div>

   <div>    <!-- div 3 -->
    {{car}} {{driver}}
   </div>

</div>
</div>
```

I would like that when I click on a certain  label that the most inner div (div 3) only show for a specific combination of car and driver. Right now, when i click label it actually affects all the divs. For instance, if i click on driver 1 then it would show all the divs3 that have driver 1. basically it impacts all the drivers 1 for each car. I do not want to use href. I have tried to give a specific id to div 3 and in my controller to activate that specific div; but to no avail. Any input?

details:
Basically, the layout will be x number of divs, x represents the number of cars. So let say i have 7 cars. I will have 7 divs one on top of another. Each div will have 4 labels (if we have  4 drivers). So 7divs containing 4 labels.
So each of those 7 divs contains the 4 labels.

Now, when i click on one driver label of let say div 1 (1 of 6); I want to show that particular inner div3 (div1.div3) without showing the other 6 divs of driver 1. So i want to be able to say for this car, driver 1 has it or does not have it. But right now, it will show me the status of driver 1 for all the cars (7 divs). It shows all the inner divs3.

```
<script>
$scope.cars = [ 'car0','car1', 'car2', 'car3', 'car4', 'car5', 'car6'];
$scope.drivers = [ 'driver0', 'driver1', 'driver2' , 'driver3']
</script>


<div0>
   'driver0'  'driver1' 'driver2' 'driver3'  
      <div 3>
      <div3>

</div0>
<div1>
   'driver0'  'driver1' 'driver2' 'driver3'  
    <div 3>
    <div3>
</div1>
<div2>
   'driver0'  'driver1' 'driver2' 'driver3'  
    <div 3>
    <div3>
</div2>
<div3>
   'driver0'  'driver1' 'driver2' 'driver3'  
    <div 3>
    <div3>
</div3>
<div4>
   'driver0'  'driver1' 'driver2' 'driver3'  
     <div 3>
     <div3>
</div4>
<div5>
   'driver0'  'driver1' 'driver2' 'driver3'  
    <div 3>
    <div3>
</div5>
<div6>
   'driver0'  'driver1' 'driver2' 'driver3'  
   <div 3>
   <div3>
</div6>


`div0`
`driver0 driver1 driver3 ....`
` -->shared space for content for drivers <---`
`div1`
`driver0 driver1 driver3 ....`
` -->shared space for content for drivers <---`
```

Comment: I didn't really grasp your goal from the explanation. Am I correct to assume that when you click a driver, you want to show all the cars associated with this driver?

Comment: @TomNijs ok, added some info

Comment: What is the relationship between car and driver? Is there a foreign key / array / map of who relates to which cars?

Comment: You can't do what you want without adding an additional variable to your model, e.g. `showDetails` as a property of a `driver`. Then, to continue that example, make click events toggle that variable and use `ng-if` or `ng-show` to display the car and driver details.

Comment: @StephenThomas care to show an example?

Comment: @StephenThomas your explanation would not care for the fact that all of them would show up. I think it requires some sort of id on inner div 3

Comment: It would also be useful if you can put a Plunker sample.

Comment: Could you give us the arrays of 'cars' and 'drivers'?

Comment: @CanetRobern ok done. thanks

Comment: @uniXVanXcel, show us code(handler), which invokes when you click on driver

Comment: I don't think this array is right. Following your arrays, each driver has all cars. We need to set your purpose more specifically. Well, I'll post a fiddle, check this please whether this is almost same as your purpose or not. https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/s9hrvbgf/

Comment: @CanetRobern yes, all cars contained all drivers as labels. then the container of the inner div 3 represents the attribute car.driver i.e car0.driver0 car0.driver1 . 
ok checking your fiddle

Comment: @CanetRobern thanks for the help

Comment: I'm sorry for that my suggestion is not perfectly proper to your purpose. But I'm glad that you've got a nice solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.cars = ['car0', 'car1', 'car2', 'car3', 'car4', 'car5', 'car6'];
  $scope.drivers = ['driver0', 'driver1', 'driver2', 'driver3'];  
})
```

```css
.driver {  
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 15px;    
}
.content {
  margin-left: 30px;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <div ng-repeat='car in cars' ng-init='temp={selected:""}'>
    {{car}}
    <div class='driver' ng-repeat='driver in drivers'>
      <span ng-click='temp.selected=driver'>{{driver}}</span>      
    </div>
    <div class='content' ng-show='temp.selected'>
        Some content for {{car}}-{{temp.selected}}
      </div>
    <br>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: thats nice thank you. One thing, i am supposed to have all 4 labels showing for each div all the time. In a sense, if i click on one label it shows its content, and if i click on a different label from another div, it shows as well concurrently; since they are independent. This is why inner div3 is an independent div as you can see in my code.  can you edit it? thnks

Comment: oh so nice:)!!  -oh actually, one last detail; each div div0, div1....div6 can only show the content of 1 driver at the time. So we can see the content for all divs at the same time but each div within itself can only show 1 driver at the time. makes sense?.. if you can fix it i ll pick your answer as the answer. and if you cant i still will. thnk you !

Comment: I don't clearly understand you, now each car's `<div>` already can show all included driver `<div>`s, not only one.

Comment: yes, i want each div to be able to show only one car. lets say div0, if i click on driver0 it shows its content, but if i click on driver1, driver0 should go away and driver1 show its content. In a sense each div0, div1,div2, etc..only have a single view for all drivers. However, all divs can show their respective content at the same time just like you did it here. so if i click on div0.driver0 i can also click on div1.driver3 and see its content while the other div0.driver0 still showing.

Comment: actually..the content for each driver in the div, should all be contained on the same space.. right now they do appear on their own, but they dont share a respective inner div 3 underneath. makes sense? think in terms of tabs. its just like div0 is one browser with tabs but they all show their content in the same space underneath..

Comment: You want to eliminate wrapper <div> around content? But, at this case, it is needed for applying `ng-show` directive. Or you mean something else, if so, post desired html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159877/discussion-between-unixvanxcel-and-slava-utesinov).

Comment: so basically, we want the inner div3 to run accross the 4 labels. width=100%
so that once we click on one label the inner div3 contains the content from the label above.

Comment: sent you chat messages

Comment: hi you saw the messages?

Comment: hey so its not really the answer .... i dont wanna remove my vote, but if you find a min can you fix it? i sent you chat messages..

Comment: hi, did you get the picture I sent? if you have time could you look into showing all the labels horizontal inside each div, as opposed to on top of one another. Maybe i can open a new question and award you the answer if youd like

Comment: actually, nevermind, i got it. will post a solution later under my post. thanks for all the help!